# Why does MSYS2 not parse a batch file on Windows?

Tags: windows, msys, mingw-w64, msys2

In order to avoid retyping a long command to MSYS for configuration, I usually use a batch file to store the command looks like below:

    `./configure \
    --arch=x86_64 \
    --target-os=win64 \
    --toolchain=msvc \
    --enable-cross-compile \
    --enable-gpl \
    --disable-debug \
    --enable-shared \`

This way works well with MSYS. But when I ran the batch file in MSYS2, it traced out many error messages like:

`'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
    operable program or batch file.
    '--arch' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
    operable program or batch file.
    etc...`

Can anyone explain me what the cause is?

Comment: Chances are you're running your batch file in a bash shell.  You want to study up on how to write shell scripts instead of batch files.

Comment: @RetiredNinja. Do you mean MSYS2 is a bash shell and MSYS is not?.

Comment: @MattMcNabb. What line endings should I use instead of '\' character?

Comment: I mean, check that there are not Windows-style line endings on the file. For example, run it through `dos2unix` and also check there's no whitespace.

Comment: @MattMcNabb. I did as your hint but it didn't help. Possibly, using bat file is not a correct way to deal with msys2. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

As you've shown it, your "batch" file looks more like a Bourne shell script, so it definitely should not be qualified as a `.bat` file.  Now, if you *have* qualified it as a `.bat` file, MSYS won't be able to run it directly as such; it needs a shebang line to make it executable as a shell script. From the error messages you've shown, it appears that MSYS2 may be trying to be clever, in a way which  MSYS does not, by handing execution off to the Windows command interpreter, (those are `cmd.exe` error messages); since the script is in Bourne shell syntax, you want MSYS2 to run it directly as such, in `bash`.

BTW, MSYS shell *is* `bash`; AFAIK, MSYS2 also provides `bash` as its primary shell.

Comment: No sir, MSYS can run the *.bat file directly without complaint, at least with my file. But anyway, I agree that MSYS2 should go with the bash script. Thanks.

Comment: @VietHa: Then your `.bat` file contains more than you've shown; MSYS *cannot* run `.bat` files directly, if they are written in the native `cmd.exe` language in which they are supposed to be. Yours, however, is *not* written in that language -- it is a Bourne shell script -- so it **should not bear the** `.bat` **extension**. Furthermore, to make it directly executable in MSYS, it **must** begin with a shebang `#!/bin/sh` line.